# How to pass jasypt encrypted password to database through DataSourceBuilder

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, configuration, jasypt

Need to store encrypted password in `.properties` file and then need to decrypt in configuration class and need to pass to database using jasypt

Trying to Encrypt and decrypt the password using jasypt in springboot application
**Reference** [link-1](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot) [link-2](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt)

Added dependency in `POM.XML`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Added encrypted password in `.properties` file

```
mail.encrypted.property=ENC(Fy/hjJHHbIYYwijL5YwXAj8Ho2YTwzhi)
```

In Springboot Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEncryptableProperties
@PropertySource(name="EncryptedProperties", value = "classpath:encrypted.properties")
public class MyApplication {
    ...
}
```

In configuration class

```
@Value("${mail.encrypted.property}")
private String password;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mail")
public Datasource ConfigProperties {
    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .password(password)
        .build();
}
```

But getting the error due to wrong password, without adding encryption code application is working fine

Comment: Did you set the `jasypt.encryptor.password` ?

Comment: @GridVost is your trying to say secret key ? which is useful in encryption

Comment: Take a look at http://www.jasypt.org/spring3.html, remember that, if you have `<property name="passwordEnvName" value="APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />` you must have a key called `APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD` in your environment. (i.e.: `APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD = MySecretKey`). This key will be used to decrypt your `ENC(...)` values.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work like so:

1. the encryptorBean! The encrypted parts are going to be decrypted through this bean. It is wired in the *application.properties* file with the *jasypt.encryptor.bean* placeholder, this is where you provide your magic word (password) for the decryption to work

**application.properties**

```
jasypt.encryptor.bean=encryptorBean

info.jdbcUrl=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyy/DEUR
info.username=ENC(1es1kdTptS7HNG5nC8UzT1pmfeYFkww)
info.password=ENC(z6selbQvJrjpxErfsERU6BDtFeweUZX)
info.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
info.connectionTestQuery=select 1
```

Then, how do I access the encrypted properties? The "magic" is done throughout the following excerpt

**The Database Configurator**

```
package com.telcel.info;

import com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.annotation.EnableEncryptableProperties;
import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PBEStringCleanablePasswordEncryptor;
import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableEncryptableProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "encryptorBean")
    public PBEStringCleanablePasswordEncryptor basicTextEncryptor() {
        StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor;
        encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
        encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        encryptor.setPassword("hocus pocus");
        return encryptor;
    }

    @Bean(name = "infoDS")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "info")
    public DataSource infoDatasource() {
        String username = env.getProperty("info.username");
        String password = env.getProperty("info.password");

        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Behind the scenes **Environment** has registered the **classpath.properties** also as an encrypted property source, hence when you ask for a property if its surrounded with ENC() it calls the **jasypt.encryptor.bean** to try to decode the property.

Hope this helps!

Cheers

Comment: @DataJpaTest  and Jasypt .